# Help in Using ClamAv

Tags: antivirus, clamav

Hi guys I installed clamAV along with clamd.

I ran this command `sudo clamscan --infected --recursive /`.

My screen stuck with the attached screen since 4 hours.

Help me to get with it.

[image]

Comment: `clamscan` seeks Windows viruses, and is meant for scanning email attachments destined for Windws.

Comment: The best advice I can give: remove it.  Or stick to scanning windows files. ClamAV is NOT designed with Linux in mind and treats files as if they are windows files. Your issue is with files that are system related and owned by root and it does not understand that concept. Totally useless. Remove it. There is currently NO NEED for a virusscanner.  Stick to the normal approach: keep password safe. make backups, don't execute random downloaded files. use on-line mails (those are always already scanned).